# Can a FRITZBox 3790 support VPN IKE v2?

Tags: vpn, router, fritzbox

I'm trying to do a `site-to-site` VPN connection from my FRITZBox! 3790 <-> Azure Virtual Network. (setup as a dynamic network).

I think I read that the vpn box I use needs to handle **Ike v2**.

*Q: Does the FRITZBox support this VPN technology - Ike v2?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should ask the manufacturer.

Comment: So the community (who are usually pretty proactive) might not be able to help, instead? Let's ask all the manufacturers all our Q's instead... :/